# active record raise recordnotunique instead of taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an `ActiveRecord` model with an email validation that validates uniqueness:

```
  validates :email,
            allow_blank: true,
            format: { with: /\A.*@.*\z/ },
            uniqueness: true
```

When I try to insert a new record with the same email, it gives me the following error:

> @messages={:email=>["has already been taken"]}, @details={:email=>[{:error=>:taken, :value=>"liberty_w@example.com"}

However, I want it to raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`.

Is this possible?

I have tried adding an email index in a migration, with `unique: true` but that didnt do anything. What else can I try?

Comment: If it fails validation it won't try and save it so will never hit the unique index (unless you use a save method that ignores validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` exception instead of an `:taken` validation error, you need to do two things:

1. Add an unique index to your database column
2. Remove the uniqueness validation from your model